# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection / Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, axios

I know there are some answers on this and I read them all. But none of them helped.
So this is my error message:

[image: Error message]

And here is my action:

```
export function registerUser(data){
const request = axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: `${REGISTER}${API_KEY}`,
    data: {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
    },
    headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }
}).then(response => response.data)

return {
    type: "REGISTER_USER",
    payload: request,
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to fetch the library for making API call.

```
function registerUser(data){
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((apiResponse)=>{ 
            console.log("api response", apiResponse) 
            return {
                type: "REGISTER_USER",
                api_response: apiResponse.data
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return {
                type: "REGISTER_USER",
                api_response: {success: false}
            }
        })
}
```

Invoking the above function

```
let data = { 
 email: "youremail@gmail.com,
 password:"yourpassword"
}   

registerUser(data).then((response)=>{
  console.log(response)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Log error and succes then check:

```
export function registerUser(data){
const request = axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: `${REGISTER}${API_KEY}`,
    data: {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
    },
    headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }
 })  
 .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
 .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: I logged data to console and I have it.

Comment: It doesn't give me a warning anymore, but is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
export function registerUser(data){
  return axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${REGISTER}${API_KEY}`,
      data: {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
      },
      headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      } 
  }).then((api_response)=>{ 
    return {
      type: "REGISTER_USER",
      api_response: api_response.data
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    return {
      type: "REGISTER_USER",
      api_response: {success: false}
    }
  })
}

//Invoking the above function
 let data = { 
     email: "youremail@gmail.com,
     password:" password"
   }      
registerUser(data).then((response)=>{
  console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: It removes the warning but I'm still not getting the data.

Comment: what data you are getting from API response. Is it empty?

Comment: I am getting newUser and it is equal to success: false

Comment: From API you are getting the response but that value is not returned to function registerUser is it so.

Comment: I think so yeah. This is like my second day doing this so I'm bit confused with all this.

Comment: Can you check from postman that the API is working correctly? IF  yes give the response object. https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: I am using Firebase.

Comment: Try this in catch block .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    }   });

Answer (score 1):

You should use `catch` handler wherever you call an api with a promise, because you don't when the api will fail and you have to handle the error.

```
export function registerUser(data){
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${REGISTER}${API_KEY}`,
    data: {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
    },
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }})
    .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        return {
            type: "REGISTER_USER",
            payload: response.data,
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        //handle error
        return {
            type: "REGISTER_USER_FAILED",
            payload: null
        }
    });
}
```

Call the function like this

```
const data = {
    email: 'asd@asd.asd',
    password: 123
}
registerUser(data).then((response)=>{
  console.log(response)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the malformed body sent to the backend.