# Request not returning any data in react-native and axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am using axios with react-native and I have POST request where I pass some data. Here is the code:

```
export function addPost(post){
console.log(post);
const request = axios({
    method:"POST",
    url:`${REGISTER_LUKA}`,
    data:post
}).then( response => {
    console.log("-----DATA------")
    console.log(response.data)
    return response.data
} )

return {
    type:'ADD_POST',
    payload:request
}
}
```

Now when I do the first console.log(post) i can see the data I passed.
But when I console.log(response.data) it gives me empty array.

How can I access response of the request?

Thank you!

Comment: what happens if you `console.log(response)`

Comment: It is still empty array.

Comment: But I get more info, not just data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection / Error: Request failed with status code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321542/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-error-request-failed-with-status-code-40)